# Billing First Name Should Be Alphabetic

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_billing_fields');

function custom_woocommerce_billing_fields( $fields )

{

$fields['billing_first_name']['required'] = false;

return $fields;

}

I want to make First and Last name should be alphabetic only. Right now it's accepting numbers also.

Help will be much appreciated. I also want to limit text of review in cart.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#billing_first_name').on('input',function(){ 
    var node = $(this);
    node.val(node.val().replace(/[^a-z]/g,'') ); }
);
```

Adding this jQuery will work.! You can add for others fields too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add fields by custom method then use follow script for alphabetic textbox:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields');

function custom_override_checkout_fields($fields)
{
$fields['billing']['billing_first_name'] = array(
    'label'     => __('First name', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('First name', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'    => false,
    'clear'       => false,
    'type'        => 'text',
    'class'       => array(
                    'alpha'
   )
);
```

and same for billing_last_name,

> use all of scripts in active theme functions.php

Actually woo-commerce does not give us this functionality. You have to use your custom jquery or javascript. This might help you

You should call this script under wp_head hook

```
add_action('wp_head', ' alphabet_only ');

function alphabet_only() {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$('.alpha').bind('keyup blur',function(){ 
    var node = $(this);
    node.val(node.val().replace(/[^a-z]/g,'') ); }
);
</script>
<?php
}
```

That's it.

Comment: Where I can find woo-commerce billing_first_name field. I am new to wordpress and woo-commerce

Comment: Pleasure ,. If my answer is helpful for you then please accept my answer.